# Match everything before first colon including colon and following spaces

Tags: regex

I'd like to match a string so that

```
A: B: C
```

would return the match (note the space behind the colon)

```
A:
```

It matches everything until the first occurrence of a colon, but includes the colon and any spaces behind of it.

The pattern `^[^\:]+` would return `A` but not the colon and the spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost. Use

```
^[^:]*:\s*
```

Demo and explanation: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pW2dE4/2)

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: Sometimes the string could be "A - B: C". Is there a regex that could match both "A - B: C" and "A: B: C" and return "A - " and "A: " respectively?

Comment: @JCarter like [this](https://regex101.com/r/pW2dE4/3)? The comment section is not really the best place to discuss follow ups, if you need something different or more elaborate feel free to open a new question :)